# What would be most elegant way to replicate data contents periodically into a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I need to parse contents from an API route and insert into a MySQL database. The aim of parsing contents is to replicate the data from the API to my database table.

I need to check API response every day (at a specified time) using scheduled cron jobs and should fetch and insert all available records into the database.There could be changes in the response every time and it should be reflected as provided in the API.

There isn't any fields which could be considered for making a unique ID as well.

I can't search and sort as its not an updating task alone, hence rather than 'updating' of records, we should doing 'replication' of data from the API. We need to consider,

- deletion of removed records from the API response,
- updating modified record fields and
- Also the insertion of new records.

**Consider an example:**

On day 1,

Let the records available with the API be A1, A2, A3, A4

There could be duplicate entries among this records .

We will be parsing the API response and insert ever record available as it is. The  script will fetch records (A1, A2, A3, A4) and insert it to our table.

Our table will hence contain records :( A1, A2, A3, A4)

Consider on the next day,

Let the records available with API be A1,A2,A3,A5,A6  -

Possible cases:

- There could updated field values for each records A1, A2, and A3 than
  day 1
- A4 is removed from the API response now
- New records A5,A6 are added now.

In this case our aim is to update the table such that, it should only have records A1, A2, A3, A5, A6 with their updated values.

The data is expected to be structured.There are specific fields from API,which are to be parsed and fetched.We can't estimate how often the changes would be made,and its asked to make update every day.

The response field values might change but not the structure.The fields for which the values should be fetched will remain same,only the change would affect the field values.

Currently there are about 2000 records ,which could increase up to 5000 soon.

*There should not be any down time as the service from this table is used in real time by another application.*
**EDIT:**
*I am parsing and inserting API response into a table which acts as a master table for another application.That application needs to work without any downtime,i.e; There should be least possible downtime even while we are doing some operations(recreating tables) over the table.*

*Sample API Response:*

```
[
    {
        "company": "XYZ",
        "company_id": 123,
        "owner": null,
        "owner_id": null
    },
    {
        "company": null,
        "company_id": null,
        "owner": "ABC",
        "owner_id": 321
    },
    {
        "company": "XYZ",
        "company_id": 123,
        "owner": null,
        "owner_id": null
    },
    {
        "company": null,
        "company_id": null,
        "owner": "PQR",
        "owner_id": 100
    }
]
```

**Database table should replicate the API response as given - irrespective of any errors/duplicates available in the API results.The API responses cannot be predicted before hand,also there isn't any direct fields which could be treated as a UNIQUE id.**

I am using PHP-MySQL.API response is in JSON format. I had seen a similar question in SO,but it doesn't caters my requirement well and it also doesn't have an accepted answer.

[What is the best way to periodically load data into table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972944/what-is-the-best-way-to-periodically-load-data-into-table)

From the above question it seems using some kind of temporary tables would be needed I my case as well.

What would be the most elegant way to approach this problem considering safety,performance and no downtime.What would be best MySQL storage engine to be used in this scenario-(InnoDB/MYISAM)?
Please advice.

Comment: Do you yourself perform any action on the database records in your local copy? If not, you could import the new data structure in a new table and after everything is done, do a little switcheroo; current table is renamed to 'xxxx_old', new table is renamed to 'xxxx'

Comment: @RichardBernards Thanks for that suggestion. In my case the contents in the table needs to up 24*7. I could understand the copying data structure and then renaming between,but is that the most elegant way to approach this situation? I am bit confused.

Comment: @SurabhilSergy when you get an update for the new data is the old data in your local copy needed ?

Comment: @SurabhilSergy i mean when you make API request will the API return all the data 2000 records for example ?

Comment: @CodingInsane **//when you get an update for the new data is the old data in your local copy needed ?//** - [I envision to perform a cron job daily,and I would like to get only the most updated API response. Old data could be saved just for future reference. The data thus scraped is used in real time for another application.]
**// i mean when you make API request will the API return all the data 2000 records for example ?//**
[API response are obtained with pagination limits.There is no filtering option.But I could get maximum up to 500 items per API call.]

Comment: in your Sample API Response will these 4 Fields change i.e Some rows may contain 5 Fields or more ?

Comment: @CodingInsane The actual data contains a number of fields out of I would be parsing only a fixed number of fields(10-12) and that won't change. There could be duplicate contents within the response.
If any such duplication is given in the database,it would be taken as it is and later as its corrected it would get modified in my table.

Comment: If you want to update realtime, you could add a flag in your local copy (something like an updated flag). Before updating, set all records to `updated = 0`. An update and insert sets the `updated` flag to `1`, afterwards you delete all records which are still set to `updated = 0`

Comment: @RichardBernards I thought of this logic,but I wasn't sure if this is the best way to do. You could better put this as an answer then :) .Still I will be looking forward to other some responses also.

With your suggestion,
updating all records won't be big issue.But I have to delete 'updated = 0' records one by one.ryt ?

Comment: I did add it as an answer, with a small addendum, have a look =)

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what your requirements are, and why the answer from RichardBernards does not suit your needs.

You talk about an array with less than 10.000 json objects, resulting in a table with less than 10.000 rows. The json and the difference between last row will easily fit in memory. You can produce a long sql-script with all the inserts, updates and deletes necessary to apply the update, and apply the update in one transaction.

One thing that is not clear from the requirements is the mentioning of the "realtime" and mentioning of this "daily" update, which clearly is a batch type. You describe your updates to be batches, but mention there is a realtime requirement?

If you really need continous access but not realtime data, you can build a new table with the new values, and do rename the tables like explained in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22108/how-do-i-swap-tables-in-mysql. Let us say you have a table called "CurrentValues" containing the data the rest of the system works on, you then build a table "NewValues" that looks like your what your "CurrentValues" table would look like in an instant. You then rename "currentValues"->"oldvalues", "newValues->currentValues" in one atomic transaction. And then perform a delete "oldvalues". If you are "lucky" the data from the API is a complete list ready to insert into your "NewValues" table.

Comment: I am parsing and inserting API response into a table which acts as a master table for another application.That application needs to work without any downtime,i.e; There should be least possible downtime even while we are doing some operations(recreating tables) over the table.

Answer (score 1):

For updates to be in real time:

> You could add a flag in your local copy (something like an updated
>   flag). Before updating, set all records to updated = 0.
>  During the
>   API result parsing process, an update and insert sets the updated flag
>   to 1. After the parsing process completes, delete all records which
>   are still set to `updated = 0`.

You could streamline this process when you receive the id's in a particular order (you would know which one is missing by first retrieving a set in the same order from the database). Than you could delete the missing ones almost on the fly.

To show this in your example; the second day you receive `A1,A2,A3,A5,A6`. You load the first 5 records from your local copy (since there are only 4, you end up with `A1,A2,A3,A4`).
You iterate over the API received values like so (pseudo-code):

```
$difference = array_diff($localCopyItems, $apiItems);
// $difference now contains all items present in $localCopyItems which are not present in $apiItems
foreach($difference as $deletionItem) {
    // delete $deletionItem from database
}
```

Ofcourse this is an oversimplified example, but that is the jist of it.

Comment: Im not sure about the order with response? How could deletion done effectively in this case?

Comment: @SurabhilSergy I have updated the answer with some pseudecode to explain what I meant.

Comment: There are no fields which could be categorized into a unique ID. only if I get some unique ID ,we could compare between local copy and API items!

Comment: @SurabhilSergy Than how will you be able to update existing records? In the sample I can see a `company_id` and an `owner_id`. Looks to me that the combination of the two renders a unique ID, right?

Comment: The response vary every day and then how could we build some uniform Unique IDs.
Here the case is as ,

company_id(null)+owner_id(null) **NOT EQUAL TO**   company_id(null)+owner_id**NOT EQUAL TO** 
company_id+owner_id(null) **NOT EQUAL TO** 
company_id+owner_id

Comment: If you concatenate the two id's separated by something unique, you would get a unique ID. Like so: `$uniqueId = $company_id . '_' . $owner_id;`, please keep in mind that an ID does not have to be an integer value per se...